# Join hive tables which are being populated in real time

Tags: join, optimization, hive

I have two tables in hive which are being populated in real time from a set of files. There is a request_time and trx_id columns in both tables where trx_id is the joining key.

I want to join them and put the result in another table (in real time or near-real time). The problem is how do I ensure that I have not missed any records. e.g. what if a trx_id had arrived in one table and not the other?

My initial solution is to keep a track of the trx_id in another table for a particular time period which have been processed and when joining the two tables exclude the records which exist in this table. However it would be a bit time consuming process. Any suggestions?